# Selecting features from a feature set using mRMRe package

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection

I am a new user of R and trying to use **mRMRe** R package (mRMR is one of the good and well known feature selection approaches) to obtain feature subset from a feature set. Please excuse if my question is simple as I really want to know how I can fix an error. Below is the detail.

Suppose, I have a csv file (**gene.csv**) having feature set of 6 attributes (`[G1.1.1.1]`, `[G1.1.1.2]`, `[G1.1.1.3]`, `[G1.1.1.4]`, `[G1.1.1.5]`, `[G1.1.1.6]`) and a target class variable `[Output]` ('1' indicates positive class and '-1' stands for negative class). Here's a sample `gene.csv` file:

```
[G1.1.1.1]  [G1.1.1.2]  [G1.1.1.3]  [G1.1.1.4]  [G1.1.1.5]  [G1.1.1.6] [Output]
11.688312   0.974026    4.87013     7.142857    3.571429    10.064935    -1
12.538226   1.223242    3.669725    6.116208    3.363914    9.174312      1
10.791367   0.719424    6.115108    6.47482     3.597122    10.791367    -1
13.533835   0.37594     6.766917    7.142857    2.631579    10.902256     1
9.737828    2.247191    5.992509    5.992509    2.996255    8.614232     -1
11.864407   0.564972    7.344633    4.519774    3.389831    7.909605     -1
11.931818   0           7.386364    5.113636    3.409091    6.818182      1
16.666667   0.333333    7.333333    4.333333    2           8.333333     -1
```

I am trying to get best feature subset of 2 attributes (out of above 6 attributes) and wrote following R code.

```
library(mRMRe)
file_n<-paste0("E:\\gene", ".csv")
df <- read.csv(file_n, header = TRUE)
f_data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(df))
featureData(f_data)
mRMR.ensemble(data = f_data, target_indices = 7, 
              feature_count = 2, solution_count = 1)
```

When I run this code, I am getting following error for the statement `f_data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(df))`:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  data columns must be either of numeric, ordered factor or Surv type
```

However, data in each column of the csv file are real number.So, how can I change the R code to fix this problem? Also, I am not sure what should be the value of `target_indices` in the statement `mRMR.ensemble(data = f_data, target_indices = 7,feature_count = 2, solution_count = 1)` as my target class variable name is "[Output]" in the gene.csv file.

I will appreciate much if anyone can help me to obtain the best feature subset based on the gene.csv file using mRMRe R package.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by modifying my code as follows.

```
library(mRMRe)
file_n<-paste0("E:\\gene", ".csv")
df <- read.csv(file_n, header = TRUE)
df[[7]] <- as.numeric(df[[7]])
f_data <- mRMR.data(data = data.frame(df))
results <- mRMR.classic("mRMRe.Filter", data = f_data, target_indices = 7,
                       feature_count = 2)
solutions(results)
```

It worked fine. The output of the code gives the indices of the selected 2 features.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with your Output column which is probably of class `integer`. You can check that using `class(df[[7]])`.

To convert it to `numeric` as required by the warning, just type:
`df[[7]] <- as.numeric(df[[7]])`

That worked for me.

As for the other question, after reading the documentation, setting `target_indices = 7` seems the right choice.

Comment: Thank you for your help!